# Installing PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, installation

In trying to ramp up on python/QGIS I've seen mentioned that python.exe is the key executable in a python install. I have both Python 2.6 and 2.7 installed on my root C: (from previous non QGIS efforts) and both those folders contain python.exe at the top level.

I noticed today that QGIS also installs Python (C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\apps\Python27); however, I noticed python.exe does not exist in these installs.

Can someone provide any insight as to why?

Comment: python.exe is in C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\bin\

Comment: Pythonwin.exe is in C:\Program Files\QGIS{version}\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin